# Change default project create location in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, format

According to the [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/project-structure) for any standard/default format for a solution, there is a ***.sln at the top level, and then a `src` folder (and potentially various other folders like `test`) at the same level as the sln, meaning the core projects will be located in the `src` folder, (similarly for the test projects in the `test` folder) not at the same level as the sln.

My problem is that, yes, you can change the default project creation location in Visual Studio Options but that will set it for the entire sln. Ideally, I would like to utilize solution folders (as they typically suggest) of src, test, etc. and when you go to add a new project inside that folder, the default file system location is C:\path\to\solution\src or C:\path\to\solution\test depending on which folder you are adding to. This makes it very easy for people adding to that solution to add projects in the right place both within the solution and within the file system for source control.

By default, no matter where you add a new project, it will attempt to put it at the same level of the solution, which means while it may look correct inside Visual Studio, the file system (and thus source control) needs to be rearranged or else the files will be in the wrong place.

If this is not something that can be handled automatically, why would Microsoft themselves suggest this layout as the default??

Please help!